# Is it good create notification inside service or main activity

Tags: android

I eveyone,

I have this doubt, I am creating a mediaplayer and I can create the notification with buttons in both, if I create in the MainActivity it will be more simple because many variable is over there, but if I create inside service I need call onStartCommand() many times and also need pass data through of intents.Then my Question is:  what is the best option?

Comment: You should follow the [guidance on building a media app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/index.html).

Comment: its ok I read but just has example in service but no explain why create inside it service